# using sizeof equivalent in objective C

Tags: objective-c

How to find the size of a structure.The use of sizeof() doesnt work in objective C.

Comment: `sizeof` does work for `struct`. Are you interested in the size of a class/instance?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761969/checking-the-size-of-an-object-in-objective-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` does work for `struct` in Objective-C. For example:

```
size_t pointsize = sizeof(NSPoint);
```

On the other hand, if you are interested in the size of Objective-C instances, use `class_getInstanceSize()`. For example:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

size_t objsize = class_getInstanceSize([NSObject class]);
```