# Memory usage for specify objects in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, memory, memory-management

I have a Cache System for iOS, and I want to add a function to log memory usage for a list of objects.
so how to calculate memory usage of custom object?

Comment: I think you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895971/using-sizeof-equivalent-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Xav, why don't you post that as answer?

Comment: thanks @Xav , the article about objc runtime is really interesting.

Comment: @Rudy SO translates my one-line answers into comments so I just do comments by default when it's a one-liner. Feel free to upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in for allot of work. Using `class_getInstanceSize()` will get you the instance size for one objects, but not for the objects that objects refers to. Each object reference will only count as a 4 byte pointer, not the actual instance size of the refereed object.

You could be clever and use `class_copyIvarList()`, traverse the ivars and ask any ivar that is an object for it's instance size as well, then recursively do the same for your superclass until you hit the root class.

Or you could just fire up Instruments with the memory allocations template, and measure the actual memory usage in real time.

Comment: seems a tough work. and also I need to check whether the object is already calculated before

Answer (score 1):

look for the `class_getInstanceSize()` function in the Obj-C runtime.