# How can I get sizeof class based on NSObject

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to obj-c . During these day's practices I noticed that every class based on NSObject can't have an entity like : `NSObject en;` in c++ but `NSObject* en` instead.
But, sometimes I need to know the Size of an Object.I can't simply write `sizeof(en)` because `en` is a pointer var.I can't simply use `sizeof(NSObject)` neither for the compiler telling me `Application of sizeof to interface 'XXXX' is not supported on this architecture and platform`.

I want to know if there is a way to get sizeof(NSObject) .If not,what the syntax is designed this for & any other ways to get the size.

Comment: Why do you need to know the size of an NSObject?

Comment: Understand that you can't create a `[]` array of Objective-C objects, nor can you allocate/free them outside of the standard framework.  And the "size" of an object may only be a small header, with the "guts" of the object in other allocations.  You really can't even *define* "size", much less make effective use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getInstanceSize)

> class_getInstanceSize
>
> Returns the size of instances of a class.
>
> size_t class_getInstanceSize(Class cls)
>
> Parameters cls A class object.
>   Return Value The size in bytes of instances of the class cls, or 0 if
>   cls is Nil.

But I doubt this is what you *really* want. Because I never found it useful and can't think a case it may be useful. (other than learning memory layout of objects and low level implementation details)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should import `malloc.h`

If you use Non-ARC:

```
malloc_size(myObject);
```

if you are using ARC:

```
malloc_size((__bridge const void *) myObject));
```

[This linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761969/checking-the-size-of-an-object-in-objective-c) is a question similar to yours.