# malloc_size return the incorrect value

Tags: objective-c, memory, malloc, sizeof

Based on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761969/checking-the-size-of-an-object-in-objective-c), I use malloc_size to measure my AAA class memory usage.

The class AAA is defined as followed:

```
@interface AAA : NSObject
  @property (assign) CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
  @property (assign) size_t bytesPerRow;
  @property (assign) AVCaptureVideoOrientation videoOrientation;
  @property (assign) Float64 videoFrameRate;
  @property (assign) CMVideoDimensions videoDimensions;
  @property (assign) CMVideoCodecType videoCodecType;
@end
```

When calling 
`malloc_size((__bridge const void *)AAAClassInstance)`
the output value is 80.
However, the byte per row in pixelBuffer is much larger than 80. What I have is 2560 by calling `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow( [AAAClassInstance pixelBuffer] )`

Do I miss any method implementation to return the correct memory usage in my class?

Thank you for precious time on this.

Comment: You can't achieve what you want. There are opaque types there, with private implementation details. Even if you find out the `malloc_size` of the thing that `pixelBuffer` points to (which is a substantial "if" in the first place), you have no idea if there are other internal pointers within that. You can't know the details of the internal data structure the frameworks are using for a `CVPixelBuffer`. Even if you figure it out for one version of the framework, it could change for any other version.

Answer (score 1):

`pixelBuffer` is a pointer, thus the `size` of it is just the size of the pointer. To calculate the total size of the object you'd need to follow all pointers, get their size and follow any pointers that it may contain.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, hypercrypt! You are right, CVPixelBufferRef is "A reference to a Core Video pixel buffer object." And I guess malloc_size doesn't recursively measure the memory usage. I need to write a method to return the correct memory usage. Again, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @willSapgreen no, `malloc_size` doesn't know anything about the structure of the thing behind the pointer you pass to it, so can't do a deep search or anything like that (and, in any case, such an approach would lead to potential cycles and throw up a whole bunch of other issues). So you'll probably need to write something specific.